# OnBoard Windows CE Development

Tags: windows-ce

I have a HP Jornada 720 that uses Windows CE 3(called HPC 2000) here with me and now I want to play with onboard development on it, but I don't want shareware programs, such as [PocketC](http://www.orbworks.com/pcce/) and [NSBasic](http://ns-basic.com). What you suggest to me?

*I'm interested on developing with BASIC and C/C++, but what I really want is to develop onboard my Jornada, don't matter the language.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [CellularBASIC](http://cellbasic.sourceforge.net/), it needs J2ME MIDP 2.0. I don't know if the Jornada 720 supports it.

Comment: It will not run. Sorry, but I want a WinCE application, not a Java one